# Puppet. Change any config/text file in most efficient way

Tags: config, puppet

I am learning how to use Puppet. An now I am trying to change config file for nscd. I need to change such lines:

```
server-user             nscd
paranoia                yes
```

And let's suppose that full config looks as next:

$ cat /etc/nscd/nscd.conf

```
    logfile                 /var/log/nscd.log
    threads                 4
    max-threads             32
    server-user             nobody
    stat-user               somebody
    debug-level             0
    reload-count            5
    paranoia                no
    restart-interval        3600
```

Previously I have wrote such module for replacing needed lines and it looks as follow:

```
include nscd

class nscd {

    define line_replace ($match) {
        file_line { $name:
            path => '/etc/nscd/nscd.conf',  
            line => $name,
            match => $match,
            notify  => Service["nscd"]
        }
    }

    anchor{'nscd::begin':}
    ->
    package { 'nscd': 
        ensure => installed,
    }
    ->

    line_replace {
        "1" : name => "server-user   nscd", match => "^\s*server-user.*$";
        "2" : name => "paranoia      yes",  match => "^\s*paranoia.*$";
        }
        ->    

    service { 'nscd':
        ensure  => running,
        enable  => "true",
    }
    ->
    anchor{'nscd::end':}

}
```

Is it possible to make the same in more efficient way? With arrays or like that?

Comment: Are you trying to allow for more comfortable notation? You can always wrap the `line_replace` type with a custom `define`...

Comment: Yes,  other variants are interesting for me.

Comment: `augeas` is an option https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#augeas, or manage the entire config with an `erb` template

Comment: Looks that augeas is not working ok with any configs. For example I can change parameters in *sshd_config * and cant in *nscd.conf*. But maybe this problem in my hands. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I wrote such code:

```
class nscd($parameters) {

    define change_parameters() {
        file_line { $name:
            path  => '/etc/nscd.conf',
            line  => $name,
            # @name.split[0..-2] will remove last element,
            # does not matter how many elements in line
            match => inline_template('<%="^\\s*"+(@name.split[0..-2]).join("\\s*")+".*$" %>'),
        }  
    }


    anchor{'nscd::begin':}
    ->

    package { 'nscd':
        ensure => installed,
    }
    ->

    change_parameters { $parameters: }
    ->

    service { 'nscd':
        ensure     => 'running',
        enable     => true,
        hasrestart => true
    }

    ->
    anchor{'nscd::end':}

}
```

And class can be launched by passing list/array to class:

```
  class { 'nscd':
          parameters =>
             ['        server-user             nscd',
              '        paranoia                yes',
              '        enable-cache            hosts           yes          smth',
              '        shared                  hosts           yes']
    }
```

Then each element from array goes to **change_parameters** function as **$name** argument after that **inline_template** module will generate regexp with ruby one line code.

And the same for each element from list/array.

But anyway I think better to use erb template for such changing.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to use the [inifile puppet module](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/inifile) to easy manage INI-style files like this, but also you can take advantage of the [`create_resources`](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/function.html#createresources) function:

```
include nscd

class nscd {

    $server_user_line = 'server-user   nscd'
    $paranoia_line = 'paranoia      yes'

    $defaults = {
        'path'   => '/etc/nscd/nscd.conf',
        'notify' => Service["nscd"],
    }

    $lines = {
        $server_user_line => {
            line => $server_user_line,
            match => "^\s*server-user.*$",
        },
        $paranoia_line => {
            line => $paranoia_line,
            match => "^\s*paranoia.*$",
        }
    }

    anchor{'nscd::begin':}
    ->

    package { 'nscd': 
        ensure => installed,
    }
    ->

    create_resources(file_line, $lines, $defaults)
    ->   

    service { 'nscd':
        ensure  => running,
        enable  => "true",
    }
    ->

    anchor{'nscd::end':}

}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Looks create_resources is another variant.  This is not ini-style config.